# Open VI Reference in LVCompare.vi

Tags: compare, labview

When running `LVCompare.exe` in Windows to check the difference between two LabVIEW VI's, I get the following error:

**"Open VI Reference in LVCompare.vi"**

[image: Open VI Reference in LVCompare.vi]

How can I fix this?

**NOTE:** *I am using LabVIEW Professional.*

Comment: I think this error message is misleading, because LVCompare is being rather careless about how it formats the error information into the dialog message - I think `Open VI Reference` is *where the error occurred*, not what the error is. The actual error is either not included or doesn't fit in the dialog box (although it looks as if the text can be scrolled?)

Answer (score 1):

`test_old.vi` was not in path when command was called. Also, absolute paths to VI's were not used.

Comment: How did you fix it please ? I'm trying to interface git over it and it gives me /tmp/ paths, not the actual ones.